# What affect does count have on sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

The following statement should return all the fields, the `count` bit is so I know how many 
foreign key's there are.

```
 SELECT a.date
      , a.area
      , a.operator
      , a.course
      , pa.rate
      , pa.notes
      , pa.productid
      , COUNT(pa.id) num
      , pa.id appliedid 
   FROM applications a
   JOIN productsapplied pa
     ON a.id = pa.applicationId 
  WHERE a.id = ?
```

The count returns the correct number however, the result only contains one lot of data.

If I do the exact same statement but without the `count` then the result contains two lots of data ( **On my particular example testing on** )

```
SELECT a.date
     , a.area
     , a.operator
     , a.course
     , pa.rate
     , pa.notes
     , pa.productid
     , pa.id appliedid 
  FROM applications a
  JOIN productsapplied pa
    ON a.id = pa.applicationId 
 WHERE a.id = ?
```

Any help, Im unsure on why the count has this affect.

Comment: Can you show us the ouput of the two queries?  Also, what language are you using to read the data?  Several languages have a foreach loop that doesn't need a count and almost all store the count of the rows themselves in whatever data structure is used to hold the results.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT()` is an aggregate function. (An aggregate function "groups" multiple rows together into a single value, the aggregated value is returned as a single row.)

A query that includes a `COUNT()` aggregate in an expression in the SELECT list will return a single row, if there is no `GROUP BY` clause.

To have multiple rows returned, to get multiple values of `COUNT()`, you'd need to add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query.